# Guess my number! c++

Tags: c++, search, numbers

I have a homework to write a program that guesses my number, but I have to do it without a number input. Only y/n question. Here my code so far, but it's not working properly. For example, it can't guess the 24,50 and 75 numbers. It works and runs down properly with a number input, but can't figure out how to do it without it, so please give me some tips :)

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

    cout << "Think of a number 1-100!!\n";

        bool l=false;
        int min=0;
        int max=100;
        int ind;
        int h;
        char answer;
        int tries=0;
        do
        {
            ind=(min+max)/2;
            cout << "Is your number bigger than " << ind << "? (y/n): "; cin >> answer;
            if(answer=='y')
            {
                h=ind+(ind/2);
            }
            else
            {
                h=ind-(ind/2);
            }
            tries++;
            if(ind>h)
            {
                max=ind-1;
                //cout << "ind: " << ind << endl;
                //cout << "h: " << h << endl;
            }
            else if(ind<h)
            {
                min=ind+1;
                //cout << "ind: " << ind << endl;
                //cout << "h: " << h << endl;
            }
            else if(ind=h)
            {
                l=true;
                //cout << "ind: " << ind << endl;
                //cout << "h: " << h << endl;
                cout << h << " is your number!\nWow I guessed it in " << tries << " tries!\nPat me!";
            }
        }while(!l && min<=max);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Do you get compiler errors or linker errors or does it run?  Does it crash?  What output are you seeing, and what output do you expect to see?  How are we to fix your code if you won't tell us what's wrong?

Comment: Guess my number? Hm, `printf("42");` seems a reasonable implementation.

Comment: This is homework. But it's clear the person has put in a bunch of effort into figuring it out. This does not in any way deserve to be closed. The question is clear and specific and enough information has been given.

Comment: tip: every line that has `h=` is wrong.

Comment: Mooing Duck:|42|warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]|

Answer (score 3):

In case of 50 on the first iteration your `ind` is 50. Then you ask whether the number is bigger than 50 and the answer for that is no. In this case you calculate `h` as `ind-(ind/2)` which is 25, then you compare it to `ind` and set `max` to 49, then continue the loop. But this is incorrect, because you throw away correct answer 50 by setting `max` to 49 in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I see an assignment in an if statement (=).  Should be an equal-to token (==).

Comment: Believe it or not, in this VERY SPECIFIC SITUATION, it didn't matter, but you should fix it regardless.  Maybe explain to us WHY it does not matter for some bonus points on your question.

Comment: Actually, it COULD matter if you allowed 0 as a choice :-D

Comment: `ind` can only be zero if both `min` and `max` are zero first.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I've read your code, it *almost* makes sense.  But your usage of `h` is... wrong.  Here's a summary.  Think about this code on the first turn when the user's number is 50, and `ind` is 50.

```
cin >> answer;

if(answer=='y')
    h=ind+(ind/2);
else
    h=ind-(ind/2);

if(ind=h)
    cout << h << " is your number!\nWow I guessed it in " << tries << " tries!\nPat me!";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to make question-guess code, but on the other hand, it'd be boring if he'd ask you 50 times if your number is 50 starting from 0, so one side of making it more interesting is making a variable for jumps but keep record for Max & Min is important, also you can add Machine Learning over the jump variance to make it intelligent